# Вывод с формы сайта в phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Не могу понять в чем ошибка, выдает : syntax error, unexpected ':', expected ',' or ')'

```
<?php try
{
    $conn = new PDO(dsn:
        "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Contagent", username:
            'vgnuchz_auts', password:
                'Mboze20013!');
                $query = "INSERT INTO message VALUES (NULL , :name, NOW())";
                $msg = $conn->prepare($query);
                $msg->execute(['name' => $_POST['Name']]);
                $msg_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
                $query = "INSERT INTO message VALUES (NULL , :name, NOW())";
                $msg = $conn->prepare($query);
                $msg->execute(['phone' => $_POST['Phone']]);
            } ?>
```

Comment: Посмотрите в доки https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php  как правильно писать  `new PDO`

Comment: К сожалению не помогает данная статься

Comment: А можно спросить? *Зачем здесь именованные параметры?* И если уж они используются, то почему тогда стоит версия РНР, которая их не подерживает?